# I can't uninstall netbeans in linux ubuntu

Tags: linux, terminal, command, uninstallation

i am having a problem uninstalling my current netbeans because i want to install another one.
However, I'm not understanding how to uninstall netbeans.

[image]

I tried to follow about 4 tutorials that I saw on the internet but most of them talked about "./uninstall.sh" in the path of netbeans, however in mine there is no such "./uninstall"

Answer (score 1):

First, run this command to check the package name:

```
apt list --installed
```

This should return a list of all installed packages and look for netbeans. In my case, I get this:

```
apache-netbeans/now 17-1 all [instalado, local]
```

Then, run this command to remove it:

```
sudo apt remove apache-netbeans
```

It will ask for your password if you have set any.